# How to install NUnit for C# with NuGet Package Manager on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nunit, nuget-package

I have Visual Studio 2015. I want to add NUnit's tests for C# project with NuGet Package Manager, and I want to have possibility of running tests with Visual Studio and in Visual Studio.

1. First I create new C# project:
   menu *File* → *New* → *Project* → *Installed* → *Templates* → *Visual C#* → *Console Application* → *<kbd>OK</kbd>*.
2. Then I install NUnit:
   menu *Tools* → *NuGet Package Manager* → *Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...* Then I install packages:

   - NUnit
   - NUnit.Runner
   - NUnitTestAdapter

   In the output I see:

   ```
   Successfully installed 'NUnit 3.0.0-beta-4' to Tmp.
   Successfully installed 'NUnit.Runners 2.6.4' to Tmp.
   Successfully installed 'NUnitTestAdapter 2.0.0' to Tmp.
   ```
3. The next step I do is adding new class with code:
   Right click on project → *Add* → *Class* → *Visual C# Items* → *Class
   name Tests.cs* → *Add*

   Then I use below code:

   ```
   namespace NUnit.Tests
   {
       using System;
       using NUnit.Framework;

       [TestFixture]
       public class Tests
       {
           [Test]
           public void t1()
           {
           }
           [Test]
           public void t2()
           {
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. And finally when I press RunAll on Test Explorer I see:

   ```
   ------ Discover test started ------
   NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering tests is started
   Attempt to load assembly with unsupported test framework in  C:\Users\Grzegorz\Desktop\Tmp\Tmp\bin\Debug\Tmp.exe
   NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering test is finished
   ========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00,0720041) ==========

   No tests are being discovered.
   ```

The strange thing is that I found no tutorial when anybody uses NuGet to install NUnit in Visual Studio 2015 and run tests in Visual Studio.

Comment: I have installed NUnit and NUnitTestAdapter successfully. How to install NUnit.Runner?

Comment: You can visit the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056195/unsupported-test-framework-error-in-nunit/38636695#38636695

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like you are using NUnit 3 beta. From the error message I'd guess the test runner doesn't support it. Try changing the NUnit package to a 2.x version and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: It worked!!! I've installed not beta NUnit: "Successfully installed 'NUnit 2.6.4' to Tmp." and it discovered tests

Comment: For those wondering how to install 2.6.4 in VS2013, since the UI only allows the latest (3+) version, run this in the Package Manager Console: `Install-Package NUnit -Version 2.6.4 -ProjectName <your project name>`

Comment: For reference test adapter 3 has now been released. Install-Package NUnit3TestAdapter

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, and my colleague solved it by installing:

[NUnit3 Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d)