# Unsupported test framework error in NUnit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nunit, nunittestadapter

I am using NUnit testing with Visual Studio 2013. We are using NUnitTestAdapter for integration of test run of NUnit with Visual Studio.

Visual Studio 2013
NUnit is version="3.0.1"
NUnitTestAdapter version="2.0.0"
.Net Framework 4.5.2

All packages are latest & installed from Nuget. There is no  build error.
We are getting error in test result window:

```
Attempt to load assembly with unsupported test framework in  D:\JuniorAchievement\Git\jaums\JA.UMS.Tests\bin\Debug\JA.UMS.Tests.dll
```

while running or debugging test using Visual Studio Test Explorer.

[image]

Test is able to run on one machine with same code on Visual Studio 2013 ultimate. We all other have Visual Studio 2013 professional version, although I doubt it has nothing to do with the problem.

Please Help.

**Update**

**__________**

After update to NUnit3 Test Adapter no error but still no test are discovered.

[image]

Somehow both Adapter are available but with Nuget & VS extension I can find only 
NUnit3 Test Adapter.

Installed NUnit3 Test Adapter from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d

Comment: Just update NUnit adapter.

Comment: Look at my comment here please http://stackoverflow.com/a/35060176/4019586 Maybe it will help.

Comment: @DenisKoreyba, thanks I will try that, just got busy with something else.

Comment: It was my bad, Architecture was x86 in test settings, I changed to x64 & its working now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run NUnit3 tests with the NUnit2 Test *Adapter*. This is not supported.

You need to install the NUnit3 Test *Adapter* through `Tools > Extensions and Updates` in Visual Studio.

Comment: Updated, but still not getting any test in test explorer & also not able to debug test too. I also tried uninstalled nuget for NUnit2 Test Adapter & updating NUnit3 Test Adapter fro extensions.  Is their any another test window for that?

Comment: Do you have a new error message? Can you run your test dll in the nunit console?

Comment: No error message. Just build occur & no test run after that

Comment: This is the correct answer, but maybe you are running into additional problems. Is your test assembly PCL or another non-desktop assembly? You should see test discovery for the 3.0 adapter in the output window. Are there any new errors or messages?

Comment: @RobProuse, @ Chris I have udpated question, after using NUnit Test Adapter 3 still no test are discovered.

Comment: Thanks Chris, It was my bad, Architecture was x86 in test settings, I changed to x64 & its working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Chris, he doesn't need the 2.0 adapter, but FYI, both adapters can be installed side-by-side if you work with a mix of 2.x and 3.0 tests.

Answer (score 5):

NUnit 3.x.y (NUnit 3.4.1) is compatible with NUnit3TestAdapter 3.x.y (NUnit3TestAdapter 3.4.0)
NUnit 2.x.y (NUnit 2.6.4) is compatible with NUnitTestAdapter 2.x.y (NUnitTestAdapter 2.0.0)

If you use NUnit 3.x.y you have to install NUnit3TestAdapter 3.x.y instead of NUnitTestAdapter 2.x.y

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 and Microsoft .NET Framework 4.x

Steps to follow for installation:
1. Open Visual Studio and create a project
2. Right click on project -> Click on "Manage Nuget Packages..." from context menu
3. From pop up window: Install NUnit 3.x.y and NUnit3TestAdapter 3.x.y
4. Now run your tests

[image]

Answer (score 1):

NUnit 3 only runs with NUnit test adapter 3 or latest version since there is compatibility issue with the older version 2.0.
so if you have an exception like this:NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering tests is started
Attempt to load assembly with unsupported test framework in  c:.......
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 discovering test is finished
then all you need to do is to install the latest version of NUnit and NUnit test adapter on to your project be right clicking referencence on your solution explorer and manage Nuget packages.

Answer (score 0):

run `Install-Package NUnit3TestAdapter -Version 3.10.0` on your Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 0):

Run this package manange console.

PM> Install-Package NUnit3TestAdapter -Version 3.10.0

Make sure that, you have selected the nuget.org in package source dropdown and selected the Test project in Default project dropdown.

Comment: Hey, this looks like your first post here, welcome to the community. It is recommended to not answer older questions unless contributing something new that the other answers do not already cover, and this answer is essentially a duplicate of @Mohlala's answer 2 months ago.