# The test method is not being shown in test explorer VS2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, test-explorer

I'm at the beginning of testing a calculation method. I did clean, rebuild, x64 adjustments to the project and I have nunit test adapter and other related dlls yet I still cannot see the test method in test explorer pane. Could someone help, is there something missing about the code or what?

```
namespace Ninja.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SinglePricingTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void ShouldCalculate()
        {
            var pricingModelTest = new PricingModel();
            var Sut = new PriceCalculationService(); // Sut: System under test
            var Result = Sut.Calculate(pricingModelTest);
            var TestParameters = new PricingCostParameters();


            Assert.That(Result, Is.EqualTo(TestParameters));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of VS? And do you want to see this test using MSTest runner or R#?

Comment: Version is 2013 and i want to see the test in test explorer.

Comment: Do you include `NUnit.Framework`? Also if I open the test explorer and hit rebuild all my tests show up.

Comment: Yes, i have. Mine is not showing up after rebuild.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I am almost sure you have the wrong adapter for your NUnit framework.**

If you use NUnit 3.0 or later you need to use "NUnit 3.0 Test Adapter" which you can download here https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/3.0.8-ctp-8.

Remove all other adapters that you don't need.

Comment: That's right. While we were reviewing with my collab we figured out that i've used the wrong adapter. Thanks, i appreciate.