# Is NUnit Test tool for windows is removed from NUnit 3.0.1

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

In old times we used Nunit window test tool.

[image]

Right now I am facing some issue with Nunit test adapter & it's not displaying tests in Visual Studio. [Unsupported test framework error in NUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056195/unsupported-test-framework-error)

Now I can find only NUnit Console and no window tool. Any tool available to open NUnit test project out of visual studio for execution & results?

I have installed Nunit 3.0.1 (latest available) on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run NUnit 3.0 tests in Visual Studio you need to use the NUnit3 Test Adapter.

https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/wiki

Comment: There was some issue in using NUnit3 Test Adapter as I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056195/unsupported-test-framework-error/. Now its resolved thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new [GUI Runner](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-gui) currently under developement - version 0.1 is expected soon. This is the replacement for the GUI you're currently using.

The other option, as Johan said, is to use Visual Studio's built in Test Runner, and install the NUnit3 Test Adapter, either as a Nuget Package, or a Visual Studio Extension.